# When I public batch (upload csv files) in Amazon Mechanical Turk, it always pumped errors for the row after my last data observation?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am trying to publish a batch on Amazon Mechanical Turk.

All the design part and csv file organizing part have been done by my professor and I. I am pretty sure these parts are correct.

However, my data only has 27921 rows (the last line number in csv is 27921). But after I click publish tab, the MTturk always pumped up an error message regarding the line 27922, which is completely empty in my file!

I have tried to download the template and paste my original data into that template. It didn't work.

The Error is:

> Line 27722: Row has 1 column while the header has 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem.

For some reason mturk doesn't identify a new blank line as an end of the file.

I opened the csv file in a text editor (in my case notepad++ but I guess a regular text editor will work aswell) and **just deleted the last line**.